# SFML 2.4's RectangleShape is running slow when rendered multiple times

Tags: c++, sfml, vertex-arrays

I am creating a level for my game and currently, there is a Tile class where I have a black RectangleShape rendering without any weirdness, except when I look at the FPS, its 200. Now, I have a pretty bad computer, but Normally when it just has my player texture on the screen, it was at 1200 FPS. Is this normal? I know that SFML 2.4.1 does not support batching. For that you would have to use a VertexArray. So, I replaced the RectangleShape with a VertexArray and used `vertices[0].position = ...` for the 4 vertices. Yet even if I set the color of the vertices to black, there are no black boxes on the screen. (This is now running at 500fps). I am sure that all the render methods are being called each frame. (`window.draw(vertices);`). TL;DR I need a way to optimise RectangleShape rendering within C++.

I am sincerely sorry if this is a nooby question or if the construction of this question is bad.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't give any direct insight, but when in doubt, you may want to profile your code. You may want to build SFML from source to see if there's a specifically problematic bit of source.